# asus x540sa hdmi output port

Tags: drivers, 20.04, laptop, hdmi, intel

How do I activate my hdmi output port in 20.04?

lg monitor wfhd 34bk650

Already checked in software+updates but no drivers listed there.

```
 *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Integrated Graphics Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 21
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:126 memory:80000000-80ffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Comment: There must be some Fn+Fx to switch on an external monitor.

Comment: Look for Displays under Settings, and see whether you can configure your external display there.